# Email content is not changing after i send email with template

Tags: send-email, activityhistory

I am sending an email using send email button at case record level. Where I've selected template and modified some data

[image]

After I sent, I have received the original content of the template. I suppose to receive mail with the body "THIS IS FOR TESTING" as shown in above picture.

But I've received original content as shown in below. In Activity, history email is saving with original content of a template. This should not happen. In activity history, mail should have the body "THIS IS FOR TESTING".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen scenarios where, if we use Custom email template then either it's difficult to edit the template before sending or after sending emails the body of the template remains unchanged.

So, prefer to use **HTML email template** with letterhead if you really want to see edited body after receiving emails. During creation of template be sure to unlock the body section. Then only, you will see edited body after receiving email.

Here is an example, of locking or unlocking the section. Clicking on lock icon this message will popup.

[image: HTML Template]